# protractor Page Object - method is not being called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor, end-to-end

I am in the process of learning protractor using paject object. Here is my Page object file and my test spec. files:

**Page Object (file name PO_Login.js)**

```
var ptor;
var LoginPage = function () 
{
        ptor = protractor.getInstance();
        this.login = function()
        {
            console.log("here");        
            var user=ptor.findElement(protractor.By.id("username"));
            user.sendKeys('admin');
            var pwd=ptor.findElement(protractor.By.id('password'));
            pwd.sendKeys('admin');
        }
}
module.exports = new LoginPage();
```

**My Test spec file**:

```
var ptor;
describe(
    'homepage', 
    function() 
    {
        var LoginPage = require('./LoginPO.js');
        beforeEach(
            function() 
            {
                ptor = protractor.getInstance();
                var driver=ptor.driver;
                ptor.driver.get('http://localhost/xxxxxxxxxx/login');
                ptor.waitForAngular();
            }
        );

        it(
            'xxxx',
            function()
            {
                ptor = protractor.getInstance();
                ptor.driver.findElement(protractor.By.tagName('html'))
                    .getAttribute('ng-app').then(function(text)
                        {
                            expect(text).toBe('xxxxxxx.sso')
                        }
                    );

                ptor.driver.findElement(
                protractor.By.tagName('body')).getAttribute('id')
                    .then(function(text)
                        {
                            expect(text).toBe('cas')
                        }
                    );
            },
            10000
        );

        it(
            'login', 
            function() 
            {       
                console.log("here...");
                LoginPage.login;
                //  var ctrlpoints_url=ptor.getCurrentUrl();
                //  expect(ctrlpoints_url).toContain('http://localhost/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/#/dashboard/points');
                //  expect(loginPage.header.getText()).toEqual('xxxxxx');     
             }
        );    
    }
);
```

I am not sure what is wrong - the login method defined in Page object is not getting called. I used console.log() to debugg the script.

Answer (score 1):

You are *not calling the `login` function*. Replace:

```
LoginPage.login;
```

with:

```
LoginPage.login();
```

---

Aside from that, instead of using `ptor` or `protractor` globally defined objects, use `browser`, `element` and `by`, see examples [here](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/tutorial) - it would, at least, make your code cleaner.

Comment: Thanks alecxe. I could use the example and create a page object and execute one test for that page. But, when I called another page object in my test script then protractor fails with following message: AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\error.js:113 
 var template = new Error(this.message);
                 ^
 UnknownError: JavaScript error in async script. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
 Command duration or timeout: 111 milliseconds

Comment: Here is some additional comments about the problem that I currently facing: I gave defined a var like var apphomepage = require('./AppHomepage_PO.js'); and I could call a few methods defined in AppHomepage_PO (Page object). But when I defined another var like var pointspage = require('./points_PO.js'); and try to call methods defined in points_PO.js (Pabe object) I am getting error as mentioned above. Any idea?